# Azure Backup VM - Can't restore

Tags: azure

I have successfully used Azure Backup to backup my Azure IaaS VM but i can't recover it because it states "You must specify a storage account"

My storage account is definitely in the same region as the backup vault (North Europe), and it is Geo-Redundant, but still it does not appear in the list. I even tried creating a locally redundant one but this doesn't appear in the drop-down either - anyone else come across this?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/backup-azure-restore-vms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working in the end, but there were a couple of Gotcha's. First my existing storage account's, although in the same region as the backup vault, were in an Affinity Group, these did not show in the restore dropdown. Secondly, when I created a new Storage Account directly in the Region (North Europe). it didn't show initially, i came back to it an hour later and it appeared.

So, patient & persistence is the key (as with all things)

BTW: Unlike with a storage account, there is no option to create an Backup vault in an Affinity Group, just directly a Region.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following
1) Storage account type is LRS, GRS or RAGRS
2) Storage account is non-premium
3) Storage account is in the same region as the vault
4) Try a different browser

If you face the issue share your subscription id.